# WinDbg load MSEC.dll

Tags: windbg

I want to load MSEC.dll in windbg Version 6.12.0002.633 X86.
when I  use the command !load MSEC.dll
it says:

> The call to LoadLibrary(MSEC.dll) failed, Win32 error 0n127
>       "The specified procedure could not be found."
>   Please check your debugger configuration and/or network access.

I changed the version to 6.11 and I also installed visual studio 12 run time with version 12 but it doesn't work!

Is there any way to handle this issue?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue in WinDbg 6.12 nor in 6.2 with MSEC 1.6 on Win 7 SP1 x64. Which version of MSEC are you using and what OS do you have?

Comment: Why use 6.12 at all? See [WinDbg versions](http://debugging.wellisolutions.de/windbg-versions/)

Comment: hi, I use windbg 6.12002.633 on a windows XP service pack 3. and I failed to merge MSECExtensions_1_6_0 with the windbg!

Comment: I am seeing this issue with WIn10 + WinDBG 10.0. Anyone is aware of the problem and fixed it? error: "Win32 error 0n2"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we extract Bang Exploitable (!Exploitable) it creates 2 Folders:

1. x64
2. x86

Open the folder as per your Project Bit Size. Now inside that folder, you will get 2 another folders:

1. Release
2. Debug

Copy the files from release folder to the folder that contains the executable of windbg.

Sometimes you may also need to change the version of windbg for making it compatible with bang exploitable.

---

**Download**

http://download.microsoft.com/download/A/6/A/A6AC035D-DA3F-4F0C-ADA4-37C8E5D34E3D/setup/WinSDKDebuggingTools/dbg_x86.msi

Comment: With the old version of windbg it is not possible to open all executables. So is there any other fix you are aware of?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue (winxp sp3, windbg 6.12..., !exploitable 1.6). Installing CRT 11 runtime did not work for me. So, the only solution I've found is to use the older version of !exploitable (1.0.6), you can download it here: https://msecdbg.codeplex.com/releases/view/28935

Answer (score 0):

I spent all morning trying to figure this out.

Codeplex was retired in 2021 and this assembly appears to be abandoned by MS so it's difficult to find information.

The site I'm linking to below indicates that you need the Visual C++ 2012 redistributable installed on the target machine to remove this issue.

The same site also statically linked the required files in the source code and rebuilt with VS2017. I downloaded the altered DLL and am now able to load msec.dll with the full path to the assembly in the command.

https://blog.didierstevens.com/2018/07/17/exploitable-crash-analyzer-statically-linked-crt/